# Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site parameter

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, session

I want to clarify about `-Site` parameter. In the below line of code:, `-Site` parameter indicates the name of any web application or it is only Central Admin Web application?

```
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site "Path of your site"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Site` parameter in this case represents the URL of a site collection.

This is necessary because in SP 2013, there are *global* term sets available to all site collections, and there are *local* term sets that are local to individual site collections.  Therefore, you need to specify which site collection you want to start a taxonomy session for, so that the correct local term sets will be accessible.

Here is the MSDN documentation for [Get-SPTaxonomySession](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608087.aspx).

Here is the MSDN [general overview of Managed Metadata in SP 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402.aspx) which describes the difference between global and local term sets.